# I want to print out the elements under the row ['A', 'e'], but the result is not what I wanted and I don't understand the result from the code I wrote

Tags: python, csv

Image of a small TEST.csv I've made:

[image: TEST.csv image]

Task: I want to print out the elements from the row ['A', 'e']

The results should be:

```
21, 22, 23
```

---

My code:

```
with open('TEST.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for k in reader:
        print(k)
```

But the result I got was:

```
OrderedDict([('A', 'e')])
OrderedDict([('A', '21')])
OrderedDict([('A', '22')])
OrderedDict([('A', '23')])
```

Comment: please post your csv file as _text_. The problem is that your title column as duplicate A entries, so only last column is considered (overwriting previous ones I suppose). You cannot have a file like this fed into a dictionary, unless you skip the first line (how can csv module guess that your file has 2 title lines)

Comment: Thank you for the quick respond @Jean-François Fabre♦ I made this .csv because I saw some other .csv that used this method to sort their data. I thought it was weird so I made a small one and try to run it myself. The code the data provider gave for analyzing the data has errors. I didn't know how to ask the question I have before, but I think now I know how. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be many ways to do it, although pandas could make it easier. For example,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('TEST.csv', header=[0,1])
```

df could be something like:

```
   A
   a  b   c   d   e
0  1  6  11  16  21
1  2  7  12  17  22
2  3  8  13  18  23
```

And then,

```
df['A']['e'].tolist() # would return a list like
[21L, 22L, 23L]
```

If you don't want your integer type to be long, do something like

```
map(int, df['A']['e'].tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use pandas?

**CSV**

```
a   b   c   d   e
1   6   11   16   21
2   7   12   17   22
3   8   13   18   23
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import codecs

doc = codecs.open('/Users/username/Desktop/tmp/SE_test.csv','rU','UTF-8')
df = pd.read_csv(doc, sep='   ', lineterminator='\n',engine='python')

print (df.iloc[0].e, df.iloc[1].e, df.iloc[2].e)
```

**OUT**

```
21 22 23
```

Important to get the separator exact

The mapping below for 3.7 would be

```
print (list(map(int, df.e.tolist())))
```

**OUT**

```
[21, 22, 23]
```